# Attacks on email validity service

Tags: attack-prevention, replay-detection

In order to have a better user experience during registration on mobile apps, I had added a web service to check if email ID exists before submitting the form. Based on the error logs, it looks like someone is misusing that API to check what email addresses exist in my database. Some of my friends told me attackers are using the email addresses recently leaked from some large organizations.

Is there a way to prevent such attacks? I doubt that closing down the email validity web-service is a good idea - almost all the authentication services seem to be offering this feature.

Note to moderators: I don't know what tags to use for this question, please do suggest some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to delay such attacks in such a manner they would not want to spend time doing it. Make the check manual, and rate limit it per IP to 1 every X seconds. A user won't care much(depending on how long X is), and an attacker will. Especially if they want to check a LOT of emails.

To do this you'll need a cache of IP addresses that use that service, and give them a lifetime of X seconds. If they use the service and the IP is in the cache then respond with an error from the service.

Then in the form, after they're done typing the email for X seconds send of the request to check.

This will mean automated systems will not be able to use your service without delay as well, but you'd be surprised how useful that is in preventing these attacks when it no longer becomes worthwhile to them to spend time attacking it.

Comment: Using xsrf protection is a must, device fingerprinting is worth considering too.